# Filter array of objects against another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of objects

```
var data = [
    {
      "body_focus": "upper",
      "difficulty": "three",
      "calories_min": "122",
      "calories_max": "250"
    },
    {
      "body_focus": "upper",
      "difficulty": "three",
      "calories_min": "150",
      "calories_max": "280"
    },
    {
      "body_focus": "lower",
      "difficulty": "two",
      "calories_min": "100",
      "calories_max": "180"
    },
    {
      "body_focus": "total",
      "difficulty": "four",
      "calories_min": "250",
      "calories_max": "350"
    }
]
```

I want to filter that array of objects against another object

```
var myObj = {
    "upper": true,
    "three": true
}
```

so now `myObj` has a key `"upper"` and `"three"` and their values are `true`. So based these values I want to make a function to get all the objects in the `data` array that its key `"body_focus"` has value of `"upper"` and `"difficulty"` key that has a value of `"three"`

so the function should return only these objects

```
[
    {
      "body_focus": "upper",
      "difficulty": "three",
      "calories_min": "122",
      "calories_max": "250"
    },
    {
      "body_focus": "upper",
      "difficulty": "three",
      "calories_min": "150",
      "calories_max": "280"
    }
]
```

this is how I tried to approach the problem

```
var entry;
var found = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    entry = data[i];
    for(var key in myObj) {
        if(entry.body_focus.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            found.push(entry);
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

my code above only checks for the key `body_focus` , so how can I check for both `body_focus` and `difficulty` ? it might seem silly but I've been stuck for hours and can't find a solution

Comment: why not use the keys with the value as search criteria, like `{ "body_focus": "upper", "difficulty": "three" }`?

Comment: I think you are vaguely looking for $.grep...but won't be possible with your current obj structure

Comment: It's better to use lodash for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick I think.

```
var myObj = {
    "upper": true,
    "three": true
}
var found = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    entry = data[i];
    if(myObj[entry.body_focus] && myObj[entry.difficulty]) {
      found.push(entry);
    }
}
```

With myObj[entry.body_focus] you are checking if the myObj has the property upper and if it's true. Same with difficulty.

Comment: so it's okay to have difficulty as 'upper' and body_focus as 'three'?

Comment: Yea, well it would break. But why would he have the data interchanged...

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object for searching which gives the keys and the wanted values, like

```
search = {
    body_focus: "upper",
    difficulty: "three"
}
```

then iterate through the array and check all properties of `search` with the values of the actual object. Return `true` if all search criteria matches.

```js
var data = [{ body_focus: "upper", difficulty: "three", calories_min: "122", calories_max: "250" }, { body_focus: "upper", difficulty: "three", calories_min: "150", calories_max: "280" }, { body_focus: "lower", difficulty: "two", calories_min: "100", calories_max: "180" }, { body_focus: "total", difficulty: "four", calories_min: "250", calories_max: "350" }],
    search = { body_focus: "upper", difficulty: "three" },
    result = data.filter(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(search).every(function (k) {
            return o[k] === search[k];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using a combination of `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.every` to match all the values in your data object with the keys in the param object.

```js
var data = [
  {"body_focus": "upper", "difficulty": "three", "calories_min": "122", "calories_max": "250"}, 
  {"body_focus": "upper","difficulty": "three","calories_min": "150","calories_max": "280"},
  {"body_focus": "lower","difficulty": "two","calories_min": "100","calories_max": "180"}, 
  {"body_focus": "total","difficulty": "four","calories_min": "250","calories_max": "350"}
]

var params = {
  "upper": true,
  "three": true
}

function filter(params, data) {
  const keys = Object.keys(params)
  return data.filter(item =>
    keys.every(value => ~Object.values(item).indexOf(value))
  )
}


console.log(
  filter(params, data)
)
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nina's answer should work for you. But in case you are interested, another way to do it:

```js
var data = [{
  "body_focus": "upper",
  "difficulty": "three",
  "calories_min": "122",
  "calories_max": "250"
}, {
  "body_focus": "upper",
  "difficulty": "three",
  "calories_min": "150",
  "calories_max": "280"
}, {
  "body_focus": "lower",
  "difficulty": "two",
  "calories_min": "100",
  "calories_max": "180"
}, {
  "body_focus": "total",
  "difficulty": "four",
  "calories_min": "250",
  "calories_max": "350"
}];

var search = { 
  body_focus: "upper", difficulty: "three" 
};

var results=$.grep(data,function(datum,index){
  var sat=true;
  Object.keys(search).forEach(function(el){
    if(datum[el]!=search[el])
      {
        sat=false;
        return false;
      }
  });
  return sat;
});
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The point being you could use $.grep to write a custom filter function and check some condition using the first parameter 'datum' or the second 'index' and return true to indicate filter match or false to indicate otherwise

Answer (score 0):

it would be a good idea to change your `myObj` object's structure to be more of

```
let myObj = 
{
    body_focus: "upper",
    difficulty: "three"
}
```

as your search object. (as it was mentioned in one of the answers)

you can then use `filter` on your original array of objects to get what you need.

```
let results = data.filter(item => item.body_focus === myObj.body_focus 
                               && item.difficulty === myObj.difficulty);
```