# Filter an array of objects by another object of filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have an array of objects who follow this structure below:

```
{
  "level": 1
  "objectId": "3756"
  "objectIdNo": 35636
  "wpId": "3635473"
}
```

I now want to filter an array of these objects by another object. This `filterObject` would have the structure below:

```
// filterObject
{
  level: "2"
  objectId: "10"
  wpId: "1"
}
```

But this `filterObject` doesn't always have all the key-value pairs because they get set manually in the UI. As a result the `filterObject` can also look like this:

```
{
  level: "2"
}
```

My goal is to return a new array of `filteredObjects` who match this `filterObject`. When only one filter exists on the `filterObject` I want to return all objects that match this one key-value pair. But if more filters exist on the `filterObject` I want to return all objects that match both key-value pairs (not only one).

### Example:

This is the data I want to filter:

```
[
  {
    "level": "1"
    "objectId": "11"
    "objectIdNo": "320"
    "wpId": "123"
  },
  {
    "level": "2"
    "objectId": "12"
    "objectIdNo": "321"
    "wpId": "123"
  },
  {
    "level": "2"
    "objectId": "13"
    "objectIdNo": "322"
    "wpId": "120"
  },
]
```

### 1.

If this is my `filterObject`:

```
{
  "level": "2"
}
```

**Return:**

```
[
  {
    "level": "2"
    "objectId": "12"
    "objectIdNo": "321"
    "wpId": "123"
  },
  {
    "level": "2"
    "objectId": "13"
    "objectIdNo": "322"
    "wpId": "120"
  },
]
```

### 2.

If this is my `filterObject`:

```
{
  "level": "2",
  "wpId": "123"
}
```

**Return:**

```
[
  {
    "level": "2"
    "objectId": "12"
    "objectIdNo": "321"
    "wpId": "123"
  },
]
```

I hope that explains the logic I want to achieve which I couldn't implement myself. I would appreciate some ideas or applicable functions.

This is what I already tried in React. The data variable holds the array of objects and the filter variable hold the `filterObjects`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const filtered = data.filter((task) => {
        if (!filter) {
          return true;
        }
        return (
          task.level === filter.level ||
          task.objectId === filter.objectId ||
          task.wpId === filter.wpId
        );
      });
      setFilteredTasks(filtered);
    }
  }, [filter]);
```

With my attempt, if I just set the one filter key-value pair I get an empty array,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects against another object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933730/filter-array-of-objects-against-another-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this result using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

You have to use `filter` and pass predicate that tell whether it is included in the final result.

In predicate, loop over all properties on the `filters` object and match if it is present in `data` or not. Simple

```
data.filter((o) =>Object.keys(filters).every((k) => filters[k] === o[k]));
```

```js
const data = [{
    level: "1",
    objectId: "11",
    objectIdNo: "320",
    wpId: "123",
  },
  {
    level: "2",
    objectId: "12",
    objectIdNo: "321",
    wpId: "123",
  },
  {
    level: "2",
    objectId: "13",
    objectIdNo: "322",
    wpId: "120",
  },
];

const filters = {
  level: "2",
  wpId: "123",
};

const result = data.filter((o) =>
  Object.keys(filters).every((k) => filters[k] === o[k])
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick!

```js
const exampleData = [
  {
    "level": "1",
    "objectId": "11",
    "objectIdNo": "320",
    "wpId": "123",
  },
  {
    "level": "2",
    "objectId": "12",
    "objectIdNo": "321",
    "wpId": "123",
  },
  {
    "level": "2",
    "objectId": "13",
    "objectIdNo": "322",
    "wpId": "120",
  },
];

const filterObject1 = {
  "level": "2",
}

const filterObject2 = {
  "level": "2",
  "wpId": "123"
}


function filter(data, filterObject) {
  const filterValues = Object.entries(filterObject)
  
  let filteredData = data
  for(const [filterKey, filterValue] of filterValues) {
    filteredData = filteredData.filter(obj => obj[filterKey] === filterValue)
  }
  return filteredData
}



console.log(filter(exampleData, filterObject1))
console.log(filter(exampleData, filterObject2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    level: "1",
    objectId: "11",
    objectIdNo: "320",
    wpId: "123",
  },
  {
    level: "2",
    objectId: "12",
    objectIdNo: "321",
    wpId: "123",
  },
  {
    level: "2",
    objectId: "13",
    objectIdNo: "322",
    wpId: "120",
  },
];

const filterObject = {
  level: "2",
  wpId: "123",
};

const result = data.filter((item) => {
  let flag = true;
  Object.keys(filterObject).forEach((key) => {
    if (item[key] !== filterObject[key]) {
      flag = false;
      return;
    }
  });
  return flag;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [ { "level": "1", "objectId": "11", "objectIdNo": "320", "wpId": "123" }, { "level": "2", "objectId": "12", "objectIdNo": "321", "wpId": "123", }, { "level": "2", "objectId": "13", "objectIdNo": "322", "wpId": "120" }, ]

const filter = { "level": "2", "wpId": "123" };

const filteredOutput = input.filter( obj => {
  return Object.keys(filter).every( filterKeys => {
    return obj[filterKeys] === filter[filterKeys]
  });
});

console.log(filteredOutput);
```

Comment: Other guys implemented it faster but anyway here it is